# Prevent setting TTL for connect-redis session to allow allkeys-lru for memory policy

Tags: node.js, express, redis, connect

I have set up a pretty simple RedisStore using connect-redis and redis packages. I have a dedicated box for my Session store and want to use the allkeys-lru maxmemory policy for eviction rather than a TTL.

It doesn't seem that connect-redis' store allows for setting no TTL (i tried using -1 in the options object when creating the store, looks like that sets a TTL of 0). Any suggestions on how to do this?

Also, does anyone see why this might be a bad practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [relevant source code](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis/blob/master/lib/connect-redis.js#L116-135), it seems like connect-redis won't let you use it without expiring the key. It seems to me that you have two options:

- Write your own session store, inheriting from connect-redis' RedisStore but overriding `set`, or
- Specify a huge `maxAge`, in order to have keys expiring far in the future.

I don't see an issue with not expiring keys and using lru instead.

Comment: thanks linus, I'm gonna go with inheriting the store and overriding the method